# Printing Images using SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to design a report where images are retrieved and displayed on the page. Essentially, like a picture catalog, where I have a header, some detail lines, and a number of pictures, depending on what is stored in the database.

Perhaps the best way is by a quick example

Christmas Pictures (master row)

```
Picture 1   Picture 2   Picture 3   Picture N
label 1     label 2     label 3     label N
```

so from the above, each picture is a separate data row, with an image and its corresponding row.

Does anyone have experience or tips on how to accomplish this?

I presently use SSRS 2008 R2, but am open to an alternative reporting tool if it can do the job.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

How are the pictures stored?   Are they stored in your database?

Like this?
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239367.aspx  (if not, please explain more)

If they are in a table (myImages), where you have an imageID, imageData, imageDescription, all you have to do is make a dataset that gathers those images and put them in a table...? Group by the imageID.  Make two rows, one for the image, one for the heading/caption/whatever, both in the imageID group (which doesn't have to show or be a column, just the field that you're grouping by).

If you need it to go across by 4 pictures each row or something, this link is really good for setting up horizontal tables: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrishays/archive/2004/07/23/horizontaltables.aspx